# unity2d loading large worlds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am using the unity engine to make a "open world" (I'm using this loosely because its mostly the same) MMO top-down shooter. I have made the world, I have a really fast system to only load the part of the world you are standing on, But It still takes 5 or 6 minutes for it to load from the play button. basically what i have done is have a massive grid of tiles split up into 8x8 sections, and those into 12x12 regions. I would like a way to load the world as you go (like from a bitmap image or something), but would I also want to be able to edit and change the world in the editor. Anybody who has done this before can you help me figure out what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just off of the top of my head, I haven't used this in a released product but you can split your large scene into multiple scenes, you said you 8x8 tiles by 12x12 regions.

I would suggest making a base scene, that loads where the player is in the world, based off of his position you load a scene and a few scenes around him, as he navigates the world or gets to a place you determine would be in range for him to see other items you load the next scene.  This is what it would look like:

```
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOXXOOOO
OOOOOXXXOOOO
OOOOOOXOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOO
```

each O represents a scene, and the X's are loaded scene.  How do you load multiple scenes at the same time?  If you take a look at the overloaded methods for `SceneManager.LoadScene` there is a method that takes in a `LoadSceneMode` Passing `LoadSceneMode.Additive`  Will load a new scene into your world. without unloading the previous scene. So depending on how intensive your game is, you could Just load the surrounding area's to the player and load them over time in the background.  The other option is to hold which scenes are currently loaded.

Next issue, being able to edit and change the world in the editor.  Inside of the Unity Editor you can have multiple scenes open at once, and move and relocate each item in those scenes.  The scary thing about this though, is to add a new GameObject to a specific scene you have to have that scene set as the active scene.

Here is a link to the documentation on Multi-Scene editting:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html

Documentation on SceneManager.LoadScene:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html

Documentation on LoadSceneMode.Additive:
https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was just wondering if I should use some editor magic to split up a large scene into a small one after I generate all the tiles (I have multiple different biomes) or if I should have one scene copied over and over and generate the world as I go.

Comment: Wait sorry you said I could just have multiple scenes open in the editor. Thanks for all the help now I can keep working on my project!

Comment: loading these scenes causes huge lag spikes, and I want to spread out the time spent loading them. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is, are you just calling LoadScene or are you using LoadSceneAsynchronous

Comment: I am using loadsceneAsync, but I found It actually causes no lag when built to my phone, It only persists in the editor

Comment: And I setApplication.backgroundLoadingPriority to low but idk if that effects anything